# GetTempPath() is displaying C:\temp\

Tags: windows

`GetTempPath()` is displaying the result as C:\temp.
The environment variables TEMP and TMP are set to `%userprofile%\appdata\local\temp` but still `GetTempPath` is displaying C:\temp. 
Does anyone have any idea why it is happening so?

Comment: What values do you get when you type SET on the command line?

Comment: How are you running your program (from the command line, from an IDE or other debugger?)?  What does `GetEnvironmentVariable()` return when passed `TMP` and `TEMP` in that same program?  I suspect that the environment for the program isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Also, check that the value of `USERPROFILE` is as expected.  Does the user name contain any non-ANSI characters?  What OS are you running?